# Difference in electrotherapy Lifepak 12

Tags: energy, device

I'm a beginner medicine student and I've got a question out of curiosity, why in defibrillators lifepak 12 or other versions..paramedics or dictors set energy for defibrillation and cardioversion in joules but for pacing is in milliamperes. Is there any explenation for that?

Comment: define "pacing"

Comment: one of the function of external peacemaker

Comment: Sorry I'm not a native English speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read now that the **pacing control** is to emulate a pacemaker with repetitive pulses say after the defib is used to get the heart started but with a weak response.

"Controlled" Current does not depend on variations in contact pad resistance which causes some skin burns and reduces the charge voltage energy in Joules. So pacing uses an estimate then quickly adjusts voltage automatically to settle on the current setpoint by measuring the impulse current peak.

Pacing control offers consistent muscle force that is proportional to the current setpoint.

The **defib** uses impulse energy based on experience with pads and patient response which measures the energy that is the square of the voltage actually being adjusted.
The energy is E=1/2 CV^2 (Joules) so the charge voltage is varied manually to set the Joules before discharge.

The pacer method is more accurate but requires multiple readings to obtain feedback for adjusting the next voltage to achieve the current setting, whereas setting the Joules is more direct but can vary between machines with different C values.